# PyQt5 - Tabs having same objects

Tags: python, pyqt5

So I do not want to use a layout for any of the tabs.  I will be using .setGeometry to place the objects, as there is many objects to be placed :)

The problem is:  Any object created in Tab1.py and Tab2.py are appearing on all the tabs.

- *Tab3.py code is identical to Tab2.py (just a button)*

I believe the issue is with the Parent/Child code, but not sure were I went wrong.  Any guidance would be much appreciated.  *You can also ignore some of the imports, I just haven't gotten to that code yet* :)

MainWindow.py

```
import os, sys, subprocess, atexit, PyQt5, pyodbc, time, datetime, getpass, csv, xlsxwriter
import Tab1, Tab2, Tab3

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTabBar, QLayout, QLabel, QLineEdit, QMainWindow, QTabWidget, QWidget, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QGroupBox, QRadioButton, QTextEdit, QCheckBox, QInputDialog, QFileDialog, QProgressBar, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    # define main window size and position on screen
    def __init__(MainWindow, parent=None):
        super().__init__()

        MainWindow.left = 50
        MainWindow.top = 50
        MainWindow.width = 720
        MainWindow.height = 600
        MainWindow.setGeometry(MainWindow.left,
                               MainWindow.top,
                               MainWindow.width,
                               MainWindow.height)

        MainWindow.table_widget = MainWindowWidget(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(MainWindow.table_widget)

        MainWindowWidget()


class MainWindowWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        # configure layout
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        # initialize tab screen
        self.tabs = QTabWidget()
        self.tab1 = QWidget()
        self.tab2 = QWidget()
        self.tab3 = QWidget()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabs)

        # add tabs
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab1, "Tab1")
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab2, "Tab2")
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab2, "Tab3")

        # create first tab
        Tab1.Tab1.CreateTab1(self)
        Tab2.Tab2.CreateTab2(self)
        Tab3.Tab3.CreateTab3(self)


    def exit_handler(self):
        print('closing application')
        atexit.register(exit_handler(self))


# create main window and show it
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = MainWindow()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Tab1.py

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QLineEdit, QMainWindow, QTabWidget, QWidget, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout, \
    QVBoxLayout, QGroupBox, QRadioButton, QTextEdit, QCheckBox, QInputDialog, QFileDialog, QProgressBar, QTableWidget, \
    QTableWidgetItem, QComboBox

import MainWindow

class Tab1(QMainWindow):

    def CreateTab1(tab1, parent=None):

        # reference number input box
        tab1.label_input_reference_number = QLabel(tab1)
        tab1.label_input_reference_number.setText('Reference Number')
        tab1.label_input_reference_number.setGeometry(25, 80, 115, 20)

        tab1.input_reference_number = QLineEdit(tab1)
        tab1.input_reference_number.setGeometry(170, 80, 215, 20)

        # add CheckGroupButton
        tab1.Button = QPushButton(tab1)
        tab1.Button.setText("Button")
        tab1.Button.setGeometry(385, 105, 100, 20)
```

Tab2.py

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QLineEdit, QMainWindow, QTabWidget, QWidget, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout, QGroupBox, QRadioButton, QTextEdit, QCheckBox, QInputDialog, QFileDialog, QProgressBar, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem

class Tab2(QMainWindow):

    def CreateTab2(tab2):

        # add button
        tab2.Button = QPushButton(tab2)
        tab2.Button.setText("Another button")
        tab2.Button.setGeometry(300, 585, 100, 20)
```

Comment: "I do not want to use a layout" That's a terrible idea, especially considering your code: using fixed geometries is rarely a proper solution, as layouts are what's really required to ensure that all widgets get the space they require in order to keep the UI usable. For instance, as soon as you resize the window and make it smaller than 400 pixel wide, the button becomes invisible. Setting a fixed/minimum size for the window won't help you a lot, as you *never* know the user configuration: if the user has very large font as system default, the text in all your widgets becomes partially hidden.

Comment: That's not the only problem (excluding what pointed out by Tim's answer), as it seems you are underestimating the importance of *naming* objects. You're using the name `MainWindow` for 3 very different things: the class, the instance reference in its methods, and the instance created at the end; this is another terrible idea, which sooner or later will cause problems. Then, you're naming `table_widget` a widget that actually contains a *tab* widget (so, definitely not a table). You're also creating a further `MainWindowWidget` instance, which is useless as it's not referenced and gets ->

Comment: -> instantly destroyed. Then you're using methods of the `Tab` classes like they were static methods, which makes their existence useless (and their QMainWindow inheritance pointless, as you could have done the same with a basic python object class). Also note that `width` and `height` are existing dynamic properties of all Qt widgets, and you should not overwrite them with static values. Finally, for future reference, ensure that you're only using imports that are necessary for the code you're providing: there are 8 modules (9, with atexit) and 12 classes that are useless for your example.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab1, "Tab1")
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab2, "Tab2")
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab2, "Tab3")

        # create first tab
        Tab1.Tab1.CreateTab1(self)
        Tab2.Tab2.CreateTab2(self)
        Tab3.Tab3.CreateTab3(self)
```

You have all of the tab controls being owned by the parent.  (Also, you have tab2 in there twice.)  You want:

```
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab1, "Tab1")
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab2, "Tab2")
        self.tabs.addTab(self.tab3, "Tab3")

        Tab1.Tab1.CreateTab1(tab1)
        Tab2.Tab2.CreateTab2(tab2)
        Tab3.Tab3.CreateTab3(tab3)
```

However, this is an odd way to do it.  You should have `Tab1`, `Tab2` and `Tab3` derive from QWidget, and do this:

```
        self.tab1 = Tab1.Tab1()
        self.tab2 = Tab2.Tab2()
        self.tab3 = Tab3.Tab3()
```

That way, you don't need a strange class method to configure things.

Answer (score 0):

Here's why: the `tab{i}` variable you're passing into each `CreateTab{i}(tab{i})` function is the same variable each time; `self` as referenced in `MainWindow`. Here's what I'd do; instead of passing `self` into the call `Tab{i}.Tab{i}.CreateTab{i}(self)`, instead pass in `self.tab{i}`, the variable you stored earlier. That way separate objects (not the same `self` i.e. `MainWindow`) are receiving the separate children widgets.